# How should I protect an algorithm that I want to sell?

Tags: source-code, algorithm

I created a trading algorithm which I want to sell. People would be able to buy the "bot" at my website and it would run from there on (if this is even safe to do).

What is the best way to secure my algorithm its code? I created it in Javascript so if I run it straight on the website itself people could just F12 and see my code. I want to make it at least hard for hackers to steal my algorithm since I know that as good as everything is hackable but just not very easy.

I've been thinking of running my bot on a different server, from there all the trading for all accounts would be made. When bought or sold it would send my website a message with "buy" or "sell" so I could show users the bot bought etc. Is this a safe way?

Comment: If your algorithm is truly novel, then you may want to consider applying for a patent to protect it.

Comment: I understand, but what if someone steals the algorithm and runs it on its personal computer? In such case no one can know he actually stole my algorithm and the person can just trade without paying. Is the standard copyright on code not enough btw?

Comment: So, what do you want to *protect against*? You don't want people to use it even once without your express control?

Comment: Against people that could reuse my algorithm. Yes, if they could use it without buying it at my website then my website would be basicly useless right? Sorry if im unclear :(

Comment: <Slightly-tongue-in-cheek> If the algorithm's any good, why sell it? Why not just use it yourself to make money that way? If it's _not_ any good, why would people buy it? </Slightly-tongue-in-cheek> As schroeder says in a comment to their answer, the only real way to protect the algorithm is to run it on your servers (or ones under your control) and not in JS within users browsers.

Comment: @TripeHound Why should I keep it to myself? If I can use it myself and also can sell it for other users so I earn extra money. Money from users and my own bot. I dont see how making a bot public for others could ruin the money making/algorithm part. I can understand that if everyone in the world would invest in my bot that my bot would affect the market so much that making predictions would be easy or you may even get into a infinite loop of not being able to buy.

Comment: @Allart As I said, I was being somewhat tongue-in-cheek... I spend a lot of time on the [Personal Finance & Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/) exchange, and there are frequent questions about people selling trading algorithms / methods (or selling access to them). In many cases, the situations described are at least "slightly suspicious", if not obvious scams: the usual responses include something along the lines of "_if their methods are so good, why don't the sellers just use it themselves?_". [**cont**]

Comment: @Allart [**cont**] **Please be assured** that I am **not in anyway** accusing you of wanting to sell a dodgy algorithm. If you've genuinely got something with potential, and want to share it, then go ahead and the best of luck.

Comment: @TripeHound I truly think I do have a good algorithm, but I start to belive there are issues I dont know yet, so thnx for giving me the best of luck xD. I think the algorithm is just not the biggest issue for selling a good money making concept. Its most of the times making sure there are no risks for users when they invest in me. People would call these scam I guess. So far my algorithm makes 100% in 7 months on bitcoin. And once had 600% on etherium after 1.5 year so that should be good. I just need the risk free investment :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you hand to someone can be cracked, known, and ultimately under their control. You can try to make it difficult to understand or use, but that will ultimately fail.

So, you need to change your business model to retain control over the process, or not care if someone uses it without your permission.

Comment: So how should I retain control of such a process? Could you maybe share a link with such information if there is one?

Comment: You run the algorithm on a system you control. I'm not sure what link you need for that concept.

Comment: @Allart Have a look at other businesses that offer similar things and see how they secure things. You will find that you simply cannot control how people do things. Once it becomes known how your algorithm works, people can simply copy it.

Comment: @MechMK1 Hmmm, that sucks xD. Schroeder, I was searching for something like [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14671/keeping-valuable-algorithms-secret). But I know enough for now, ty guys.