# Criteria for an ADSL wireless modem

Tags: wireless

I'm going to buy a new ADSL wireless modem, and what really matters to me is security.
So, what are the criteria I should consider, and which security features should I look for?
How should I compare the modems in terms of the security (for example, WPA2 > WPA > WEP !!!)?

Answer (score 1):

As far as the modem functionality itself, it doesn't really matter that much.  Unless someone is taping your phone line (which is normally done at the ISP's end now anyway) then it won't matter a bit.  It's a wired connection that isn't going across a public network.

If the ADSL modem also provides router functionality, then the same advice as a router would apply.  You'd want a strong firewall and good wireless encryption.  For more info on router functionality to look for, you can look at [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1244/securing-the-security-guys-home-office-what-should-we-do) which already answers it.

Comment: "...strong firewall and good wireless encryption". Can you explain a little more?

Answer (score 0):

You should be ok with WPA2-PSK AES and a random strong password as that is the biggest downfall of WPA protocol. Ensure that WPS(wifi protected setup) is disabled as this is flawed and easy to crack. Additional security features can include MAC filtering and diabling SSID broadcasting but these also have shortcomings of course.